# No rule to make target -project

Tags: ios, macos

Thanks for any help with this, this error is happening when i execute make:

```
XBUILD=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild
PROJECT_ROOT=.
PROJECT=$(PROJECT_ROOT)/InfColorPicker.xcodeproj
TARGET=InfColorPicker


all: lib$(TARGET).a

lib$(TARGET)-i386.a: $(XBUILD) -project $(PROJECT) -target $(TARGET) -sdk iphoneos -arch armv7 -configuration Release clean build -mv $(PROJECT_ROOT)/build/Release-iphoneos/lib$(TARGET).a $@ 

lib$(TARGET)-armv7.a: $(XBUILD) -project $(PROJECT) -target $(TARGET) -sdk iphoneos -arch armv7 -configuration Release clean build -mv $(PROJECT_ROOT)/build/Release-iphoneos/lib$(TARGET).a $@

lib$(TARGET)-arm64.a: $(XBUILD) -project $(PROJECT) -target $(TARGET) -sdk iphoneos -arch arm64 -configuration Release clean build -mv $(PROJECT_ROOT)/build/Release-iphoneos/lib$(TARGET).a $@

lib$(TARGET).a: lib$(TARGET)-i386.a lib$(TARGET)-armv7.a lib$(TARGET)-arm64.a xcrun -sdk iphoneos lipo -create -output $@ $^ 

clean: -rm -f *.a *.dll -rm -rf build
```

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Comment: I am also facing the same error.